# Sorting a view by criterion1 OR criterion2

Tags: 7, views

Is there a way to sort a view by criterion1 **OR** criterion2? In a view's filter setting there is an option to and/or/rearrange - is there something similar for sorts?

Comment: Sounds like you're trying to implement an SQL `ORDER BY CASE WHEN ...`, which I don't think Views can handle. You might have to alter the query manually

Comment: Thanks, Clive. I ended up using search_api_sorts for this.